# Question about the maximum principle for the Laplace's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, harmonic-functions

Maximum principle for the Laplace's equation:

$$\nabla^2 u= \Delta u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$$
$$\Delta u=f(x,y) \text{ Poisson }$$

Problem with boundary values of the form Dirichlet:

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\Delta u=f(x,y), (x,y) \in D\\ 
u=h(x,y), (x,y) \in \partial D
\end{matrix}\right\}:(0)$$
The equation is linear so it reduces into the solution of two problems:

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
u=u_1(x,y)+u_2(x,y) \\
\Delta u_1=f(x,y) \text{ in } D\\ 
u_1=0 \text{ in } \partial D
\end{matrix}\right\}:(1)$$
and
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\Delta u_2=0 \text{ in } D\\ 
u_2=h(x,y) \text{ in } \partial D
\end{matrix}\right\}:(2)$$

We suppose that $(1)$ stands and we will prove the $(2)$

$$(0) \Rightarrow \Delta u_1+\Delta u_2=f(x,y) \text{ in } D, (1) \Rightarrow \Delta u_1 = f(x,y) \text{ in } D$$
So $\Delta u_2 =0 \text{ in } D$

$$u=u_1+u_2=h \text{ in } \partial D, (1) \Rightarrow u_1=0 \text{ in } \partial D$$
So $u_2=h \text{ in } \partial D$

Therefore $(0)$ is reduced at solving the problems:

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\Delta u_1=f(x,y) \text{ in } \overline{D}
\end{matrix}\right\}:(1')$$

$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\Delta u_2=0 \text{ in } D\\ 
u_2=h(x,y)-u_1(x,y)=h(x,y)-f(x,y) \text{ in } \partial D
\end{matrix}\right\}:(2')$$

($\overline{D}=D \cup \partial D$)
$$$$
Could you explain me why it is:
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\Delta u_2=0 \text{ in } D\\ 
u_2=h(x,y)-u_1(x,y)=h(x,y)-f(x,y) \text{ in } \partial D
\end{matrix}\right\}:(2')$$
and not:
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
\Delta u_2=0 \text{ in } D\\ 
u_2=h(x,y)-u_1(x,y)=h(x,y) \text{ in } \partial D
\end{matrix}\right\}:(2')$$
??

Isn't $u_1(x,y)=0$ at $\partial D$???

Comment: Hi!! $\ddot \smile$. I believe you are entirely right. Looks like a mistake in your papers.

Comment: @IlikeSerena Could you explain me why at the relation $(1')$ it is $$\Delta u_1 =f(x,y) \text{ in } \overline{D}$$ and not  $$\Delta u_1 =f(x,y) \text{ in } D$$?? (where $\overline{D}=D \cup \partial{D}$)

Comment: It does not really seem to matter does it? The relation holds on $D$ and furthermore it has well defined values $h(x,y)$ at $\partial D$. The solution assumes that $u$ is nicely differentiable on $D$ including on the boundary $\partial D$. Therefore it is nicely differentiable on $\overline D$.

Comment: Isn't $u_1=0$ in $\partial{D}$? So shouldn't it be:
$$\Delta u_1=0 \text{ in } \partial{D}$$??

Comment: You are quite right. That's what I meant. :)

Comment: @IlikeSerena Doesn't $$\Delta u_1=f(x,y) \text{ in } \overline{D}$$ mean that $\Delta u_1=f(x,y) \text{ in } D$ AND $\Delta u_1=f(x,y) \text{ in } \partial{D}$???

Comment: Yes... (Wondering)